# Logging not working on cloned environment in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

Tried logging this on devops stackexchange, but no joy - so asking here.

I have created a 3rd environment of an existing working Azure-hosted ASP netcore3.1 app by cloning the app-slot, SQL database and storage resource, modifying the relevant connection strings and configuration parameters (verified) and all is working for a new, segregated environment.

Except one thing - blob logging.

We have written an app which uses `Azure.Storage.Blobs.AzureBlobClient` - this takes connection parameters lifted from the Azure portal and downloads the files. This connects fine and downloads a set of .csv files, but not the usual .txt files which contain our application logging.  For the other environments, which use the same actual application, logging is available.

Also of note is when connecting via FTP to view the site folders, the application subfolder of the LogFiles folder is not present.

All settings under "App Service Logs" and the linked "storage container" - these are identical (but not the same storage container).

What else could be the cause here?

The code that grabs the logs is as follows:

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(ConnectionString);
var container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(ContainerName);
var blobs = container.GetBlobs(prefix: $"appname/{now.Year}/{ZeroPad2(now.Month)}/{ZeroPad2(now.Day)}");

foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    var parts = blob.Name.Split('/');
    var nameEnd = parts[parts.Length - 2] + "_" + parts[parts.Length - 1];
    var outFileName = Path.Combine(fileOutDir, nameEnd);
    if (File.Exists(outFileName))
    {
        File.Delete(outFileName);
    }

    var a = new BlobBaseClient(ConnectionString, ContainerName, blob.Name);
    using (var fileStream = File.Create(outFileName))
    {
        a.DownloadTo(fileStream);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps anyone this had to be solved by, at Azure portal level, adding in the site extension package for Azure Logging.